# What does 'pool_name' mean in CREATE TABLE-statement?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hdfs, impala

In Impala at the end of the [CREATE TABLE-statement](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_create_table.html#create_table) you can set the replication-factor as I understand:

```sql
CREATE [EXTERNAL] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] [db_name.]table_name
    ...
    [CACHED IN 'pool_name' [WITH REPLICATION = integer] | UNCACHED]
```

Anyhow, I'm a bit puzzled what `pool_name` refers to. Is this the path in the HDFS where the data is stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly, it actually refers to an HDFS pool defined using `hdfs cacheadmin -addPool...` command, see [hdfs command guide](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSCommands.html#cacheadmin). A pool, in turn, does contain a bunch of *cache directives* that reference hdfs paths to be cached. From apache doc:

> A cache pool is an administrative entity used to manage groups of
>   cache directives. Cache pools have UNIX-like permissions, which
>   restrict which users and groups have access to the pool. Write
>   permissions allow users to add and remove cache directives to the
>   pool. Read permissions allow users to list the cache directives in a
>   pool, as well as additional metadata. Execute permissions are unused.
>
> Cache pools are also used for resource management. Pools can enforce a
>   maximum limit, which restricts the number of bytes that can be cached
>   in aggregate by directives in the pool. Normally, the sum of the pool
>   limits will approximately equal the amount of aggregate memory
>   reserved for HDFS caching on the cluster. Cache pools also track a
>   number of statistics to help cluster users determine what is and
>   should be cached.
>
> Pools also can enforce a maximum time-to-live. This restricts the
>   maximum expiration time of directives being added to the pool.

The details of how to use this HDFS feature in Impala can be found in the [Impala Guide](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_perf_hdfs_caching.html#hdfs_caching_prereqs).